# Generic Attribute table for any entity

Tags: java, hibernate

let say I have something like attribute. Every entity can have list of attribute.

this looks like:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Attribute {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private AttributeValue attributeValue;
}
```

and table AttributeValue which keeps valeu for this attribute.

Let say I have entities like Contractor, Article, Invoice etc. For every one I want to add Mapping to Attribute. How can I do this? If question is unclear tell me - I will try to reformat question somehow

Comment: I would imagine a `@ManyToMany` mapping, or a `@OneToMany` mapping with a `@JoinTable` would work. Alternatively, if you dropped the requirement of having an `id` for `Attribute`, you could use an `@ElementCollection` of `Embeddable`s. Have you tried any of these options?